# How to define an unknown variable class type at coding time?

Tags: c#, class

What I'm looking for is a way to create a class (NotDefinedClass) with a simple bool variable and a "class variable" that I can declare in the constructor. The classes that I will declare in the constructor will have their own methods. And later I want to access theses methods like "ClassOne.CLASS1.MethodOne();"

```
public class NotDefinedClass
{
        public bool Active;
        public NotDefinedYetClass;
        
        public NotDefinedClass(class _Class, bool _Active){
                NotDefinedYetClass = _Class;
                Active = _Active;
        }
}
```

```
public NotDefinedClass ClassOne = new NotDefinedClass(CLASS1, false);
public NotDefinedClass ClassTwo = new NotDefinedClass(CLASS2, false);
public NotDefinedClass ClassThree = new NotDefinedClass(CLASS3, false);
```

Comment: You are looking for the variable type `System.Type`.

Comment: What is the end goal? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Yes, i used ".GetType()" and it works with the answer of Misha.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I think that I don't need a generic class or a generic type, I only put that there because is the closest thing that i found for my question.

Comment: @Gabriel Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you are trying to do. It is not exactly clear what your requirements are and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Progman I'm really trying, this is not my native language and i still don't know how to write much and express myself, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

A class is a type: we can't "*assign a class to variable*" in C#.

We can create an object instance being of type a class, or struct, and assign it to a variable:

```
var instanceOfMyClass = new MyClass();
```

Also we can get an instance of a `Type` class instance that describes the targetted class and assign it to a variable like:

```
var myClassType = instanceOfMyClass.GetType();

var myClassType = typeof(MyClass);
```

But what to do with that?

```
public Type NotDefinedYetClass;
```

And it is impossible to write this and replace `T` at runtime with something without using generics:

```
public T NotDefinedYetClass;
```

Also, it is impossible to use the keyword `class` as a type of a variable or method parameter:

```
public NotDefinedClass(class _Class, bool _Active)
```

**Solution**

A [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) object can be used... or not: more information on goals and design may be needed.

```
public class NotDefinedClass
{
    public bool Active;
    public dynamic NotDefinedYetClass;
    
    public NotDefinedClass(dynamic _Class, bool _Active)
    {
        NotDefinedYetClass = _Class;
        Active = _Active;
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer generics to dynamics, except in a few cases where they are more powerfull and simpler.

We can create a generic version of the class to solve the problem using for example a `T` artifact as a generic type parameter that allows to create as many types as needed:

```
public class EmbededInstance<T> where T : class
{
  public bool Active { get; /* private */ /* set; */ }

  public T Instance { get; /* private */ /* set; */ }

  public EmbededInstance(T instance, bool active)
  {
    Instance = instance;
    Active = active;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public EmbededInstance<MyClass1> Embeded1
  = new EmbededInstance<MyClass1>(new MyClass1(), false);

public EmbededInstance<MyClass2> Embeded2
  = new EmbededInstance<MyClass2>(new MyClass2(), false);

public EmbededInstance<MyClass3> Embeded3
  = new EmbededInstance<MyClass3>(new MyClass3(), false);
```

Having for example:

```
public class MyClass1
{
  public void MyMethod() { }
}

public class MyClass2
{
  public int MyInteger { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass3
{
}
```

To use the embeded instance members, properties and methods:

```
Embeded1.Instance.MyMethod();

Embeded2.Instance.MyInteger = 10;
```

**More information**

[C# MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp)

[Generics in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/)

[Generic classes and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

[Generics Level 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm)

[Generics level 2](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generics)

Answer (score -1):

Just use `Type` for this:

```
public class NotDefinedClass
{
    public bool Active;
    public Type NotDefinedYetClass;
    
    public NotDefinedClass(Type _Class, bool _Active){
            NotDefinedYetClass = _Class;
            Active = _Active;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your answer does not throw any error, but how do I access the methods and variables of the class that I assing in the declaration?